# possible current result of possible past event

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, conditionals

I want to express a possible result of an action that might have been carried on in past, but I don't have any idea whether the action is done or not. Consider this sentence:

> If you'd read the book, you would know what I mean..

Given the fact that I have no idea whether the listener has read or hasn't read the book, does this construct work?

I want to imply:

1. This is a strong condition, and I'm sure if the action is done, the result holds true.
2. I have no idea whether the action is done or not, and I **don't** want to express *It's unlikely that you have read the book*. In fact, there is a high chance that listener has read the book.

My inclination is if I remove would in result sentence, it might feel better:

> I you'd read the book, you know what I mean..

However, no mixed-conditional that I've found mention the last construct.

Update:

After more search, I come to this construct:

> If you've read the book, you know what I mean

I think the use of present perfect is more natural and may suggest that this action is possible. Does it? Anyway, I don't know in which conditional categories this falls into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past perfect in "if" clauses indicates a counterfactual condition: "You didn't read the book but if you had read it..."

For conditions that may or may not be true, a present perfect condition can be used, and so use "will" in the conclusion.

> If you've read the book, you'll know what I mean.

And you'll not find this on the list of zero/first/second/third conditional... again this indicates the limited used of this analysis of conditional sentences in English.

Comment: Thanks James. Is "will" in result necessary, give that I'm talking about present, not future, result?

Comment: Yes, "will" here is an indicator of conditionallity and not an indicator of tense.

Comment: So is this example incorrect? "If you have read all the chapters, you know who said or did what to whom to lead up to it"

Comment: That is actually the first sentence by which I learned I can use present perfect.

Comment: I'd prefer "... you'll know who said ...", and I'm not sure of the function of "to lead up to it" (to lead up to *what?*)

Comment: It's an excerpt from [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=0QTmM0nR_Q0C&lpg=PA66&dq=%22if%20you%20have%20read%22&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q=%22if%20you%20have%20read%22&f=false) which doesn't seem to be written by a native.